# rbind lists to data.frame in for loop

Tags: r, loops, rbind

This is a (meaningless) truncated version of my for-loop in R that calculates land uses for some polygons. It iterates nicely through the data except when it should bind the calculations to a data.frame using `plyr::rbind.fill()`. I get the desired result but also (thes same number of) additional unwanted columns filled with NA-values (I guess it has something to do with the column names).

```
agri_coverage <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3), nrow=1))
set.seed(23)
agri <- rnorm(10, 0.5)

land_use <- NULL
for (i in seq_along(agri)) {
name <- agri[i]
if (name > 1) {
  wl <- as.list(unlist(agri_coverage[ ,1:3]))
  } else {   
  wl <- as.list(rep(NA, 3))
  }
  land_use <- rbind.fill(land_use, data.frame(wl)) #combine output
}
```

What's the best function/ method do combine these lists into one data frame and why are these additional columns produced?

I tried other functions like `rbind()`, `data.table::rbindlist()` without being successfull.

Comment: `rbind.fill` (and it's dplyr successor `bind_rows`) look for the same names for each vector to align them, and your `NA`s don't have names. If you change the `else` to `wl <- as.list(setNames(rep(NA, 3), names(agri_coverage)))`, it will work. A more typical base approach would be `do.call(rbind, lapply(agri, function(x){if(x > 1){agri_coverage} else {rep(NA, 3)}}))`

Comment: I was thinking way to complicated. Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting additional unwanted columns filled with NAs is because of the fact that your list created in your `else` condition is not named the same as the list in your `if` condition. `rbind.fill` appends columns with the same name onto each other and any columns that have different names are filled with `NA`. From the `rbind.fill` help:

> rbinds a list of data frames filling missing columns with NA.

I think to get you desired result you can simply add this line at the end of your else condition:

```
names(wl) <- names(agri_coverage)
```

The code then becomes:

```
land_use <- NULL
for (i in seq_along(agri)) {
  name <- agri[i]
  if (name > 1) {
    wl <- as.list(unlist(agri_coverage[ ,1:3]))
  } else {   
    wl <- as.list(rep(NA, 3))
    names(wl) <- names(agri_coverage)
  }
  land_use <- rbind.fill(land_use, data.frame(wl)) #combine output
}
```

which results in:

```
 land_use
          X1        X2         X3
1         NA        NA         NA
2         NA        NA         NA
3  0.2182885 -1.046535 -0.2886886
4  0.2182885 -1.046535 -0.2886886
5  0.2182885 -1.046535 -0.2886886
6  0.2182885 -1.046535 -0.2886886
7         NA        NA         NA
8  0.2182885 -1.046535 -0.2886886
9         NA        NA         NA
10 0.2182885 -1.046535 -0.2886886
```